# Посоветуйте фрэймворк для консольного приложения на java

Tags: java, консоль, framework

Посоветуйте фрэймворк для консольного приложения на java,
т.е. фрэймворк должен уметь обрабатывать входящие параметры, выдавать еррор, если параметры указаны неверно или не все,
и уметь показывать справку по командам.

Желательно создающий минимальную нагрузку, вроде в спринге есть, но, наверное, там слишком сложно.

Comment: Мне кажется, написать такой «фреймворк» лучше всего самому в качестве несложного упражнения.

Comment: @VladD не зачем изобретать велосипеды в данном вопросе

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в сторону Groovy и его [CliBuilder](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/gapi/groovy/util/CliBuilder.html). Для не слишком сложного приложения должно хватить. Если вам нужен IoC, DI и прочие фишечки, то возьмите Spring, или Google Guice, или Pico Container.